# Create MVC RouteLinks with JQuery

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

How can I create MVC RouteLinks (not ActionLinks) with JQuery?

With Jquery, I want to generate html that contains a list of RouteLinks, then put those links into a `<div>`.

Something like this

```
var myLinks = '@Html.RouteLink("MyAction1", "MyController1", null, new { id = "MyId1" })' + '@Html.RouteLink("MyAction2", "MyController2", null, new { id = "MyId2" })'

$("#myDiv").html(myLinks);
```

That, of course, does not work.

Is there anything like `Url.Action("MyAction","MyController")` for RouteLinks so I can specify a Route name?

Comment: You don't. You make RouteLinks with the ASP.Net MVC framework. jQuery is a client-side javascript library that is isolated from MVC. The ASP.Net framework doesn't execute your code because your code executes in the browser, not on the server where ASP.Net resides.

Comment: Thanks Chris. There's nothing like `Url.Action("MyAction","MyController")` for RouteLinks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have would work if you do that inside of a .cshtml file, and not in a .js file.

Another option would be to have a method in the .js file that takes the links as a parameter, then inside of the .cshtml file, you simply pass in the links.

.js:

> function doSomething(links) {   $('#myDiv').html(links); }

.cshtml

```
<script>
  doSomething('@Html.RouteLink("MyAction1", "MyController1", null, new { id = "MyId1" })' + '@Html.RouteLink("MyAction2", "MyController2", null, new { id = "MyId2" })');
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Queti. There's nothing like `Url.Action("MyAction","MyController")` for RouteLinks?

Comment: Url.RouteUrl("urlName", new { id = "MyId2" })